# Git merge locally messed up. Gemfile disappeared and rails server does not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, merge, head

Did a Merge Branch locally in working-copy with master. After merging, switching back to master displays HEAD, instead of master as it was before. Also errors pops up when start rails server with rails server, saying no bcrypt file to load. Also Gemfile disappeared from the root subdir.

Ran bundle install and did not help.

Here is the output of git branch and git rebase.

```
$ git branch -a
* (no branch)
  master
  working_copy
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/working_copy

$ git rebase --abort
No rebase in progress?
```

Any idea about how to fix? Thanks

Comment: You're in a detached head state, not on `master`. Possible you're mid-rebase? What happens if you `git rebase --abort`?

Comment: What are the steps you did? You said switching to master, but clearly you did not.

Comment: It shows HEAD after switching to master. Can not display the master.

Comment: "No rebase in progress?" for git rebase --abort

Comment: You could try, git log. This shows your recent commits. Then choose the clean old commit you want to go back too. Run, git reset --hard whatevergitcommitnumber.

Answer (score 0):

As long as everything was commited, you should be fine:

```
git checkout working_copy
git reset --hard `git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1`
```

That will hard reset to your last commit on the branch. From there, you can start the merge all over again.